# How to set time in log as main @timestamp in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

Im using logstash to index some old log files in my elastic DB.
i need kibana/elastic to set the timestamp from within the logfile as the main @timestamp.

Im using grok filter in the following way:
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:@timestamp}
yet elasticsearch sets the time of indexing as the main @timestamp and not the timestamp written in the log line.

Any idea what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [date filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date) to set the `@timestamp` field. Extract the timestamp in whatever format it's in into a separate (temporary) field, e.g. `timestamp`, and feed it to the date filter. In your case you'll most likely be able to use the special ISO8601 timestamp format token.

```
filter {
  date {
    match => ["timestamp", "ISO8601"]
    remove_field => ["timestamp"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Magnus, I have made some progress yet the timestamp is still not parsed correctly. using the suggestion above "ISO8601" , nothing get indexed and no exception pops up. using "TIMESTAMP_ISO8601", i get the an error on logstash. finally, using ""YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" results in all monthes being January (i.e- 01)       ...what am i missing?

Comment: OK, Got it, replaced 'DD' with 'dd' and it seems to be working fine.  Thanks @Magnus

Comment: In my case, I also had to have a ".SSS" on the end.  [time format documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
filter {
  
   grok {
     match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tstamp}"]
       }
  date {
    match => ["tstamp", "ISO8601"]
  }
}
```